# can not display capture image in imageview

Tags: android

I have some code that capture image from camera and save the image in device gallery. after onActivityResults method i get the image url and i can see the image on my gallery on device. but i cant call that image for some reason. the url string iam get is /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1493836160696.jpg. any idea?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cancel_btn:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.next_btn:

            break;
        case R.id.camera_btn:
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                String fileName = "temp.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);
                takePictureIntent
                        .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                break;
            }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                          Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);


                Uri u = Uri.parse(picturePath);
                Log.d("path", String.valueOf(u));
                //ALBUM_ART_URI = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(picturePath));
                Picasso.with(AddNewDish.this).load(u).into(mImageView);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you got any error log ?

Comment: what Sdk version you are testing ? for sdk >= 23 you need runtime permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code in the `case` with:

```
    case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Picasso.with(AddNewDish.this).load(mCapturedImageURI).into(mImageView);
        }
```

Also, you need to make sure that you are retaining `mCapturedImageURI` in the saved instance state `Bundle`, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.

See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for how to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and the resulting `Uri`.